# React-Navigation: Navigation onPress doesn't work

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am a bit confused about this navigation system. I have root which I contain navigations in it. And I have two different screens. No problem till here. I put initialRoute and displaying SignInScreen. Also put a button for Sign Up screen but that button isn't working.

Root.js

```
const ScreenNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    SignIn: SignInScreen,
    SignUp: SignUpScreen,
},
    {initialRouteName: 'SignIn' }
);

const ScreenContainer = createAppContainer(ScreenNavigator);

export default class Root extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <ScreenContainer style={styles.container} />
        );
    }
}
```

and SignInScreen:

```
import SignUpScreen from '../screens/Signup';

export default class SignInScreen extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Sign in Screen </Text>
                <Button
                    title={'Sign up'}
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUpScreen')}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

is it something that I am missing here? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in the code, you just miss spell the route. 
There is no route name SignUpScreen, correct route name is `SignUp` and `SignIn`

confusion is due to change in api of react navigation

before we define a route like

```
Login: { 
  screen: LoginScreen
}
```

so login is a route name and `screen` is just a component we need to render

but after 2^ version, it changed to

```
{SignIn: SignInScreen}
```

so now name is `SignIn` and component is `SignInScreen`

even if you want a route name as component just do

```
const ScreenNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    SignInScreen,
    SignUpScreen,
},
```

now you route name is `SignInScreen` and `SignUpScreen`

hope this information is enough

Comment: are you sure? my components name is SignUpScreen and SignInScreen, that's why I can import and export... And do you mean: I need to change, {SignIn: SignInScreen} to {SignIn: SignIn} this?

Comment: Oh, I see it now. thank you for the example. it fixed now :) I am a bit newbie at this.

Comment: @Barbie its okay :) enjoy codding

Answer (score 1):

Issue in route name.

```
onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp')}
```

Try to keep the route names in constant file. It may make things easier to handle.

```
const routes = {
  route1: 'route1',
  route2: 'route2',
};

const ScreenNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    [routes.route1]: Screen1,
    [routes.route2]: Screen2,
},
    {initialRouteName: routes.route1 }
);
```